# Can I replace an SRAM chip with a faster one?

Tags: sram, replacement

I need to replace an SRAM chip with an access time of 25ns (AS7C256-25JC). How important is the access time? Can I replace it with one with a lower access time, such as the AS7C256A-20JC at 20ns, or even the 71256SA12YG at 12ns, or does the access times need to match?

Also, is it possible to combine chips with different access times? In this case there are 3 chips on the board. Can I replace one 25ns chip with a faster one or do I need to replace all three?

Comment: Doesn't matter. As long as other important stuff like pinout matches.

Comment: I don't agree with @DKNguyen as it does matter. Replacing slower chips with faster may not work because the overall evironment may not support a faster chip which may have stricter requirements than slower chips. It may require larger currents faster and problems ensue if it is not available. Also signals may have faster slew rate so transmission line issues may arise. And more EMI/EMC issues.The usual stuff when replacing slower chips to faster.

Comment: Timing (and race conditions) mean that such replacement can cause difficulties; this is a re-design decision, and reverse-engineering to analyze the original is required.

Comment: The 20ns part would be my choice - same chip that passed the the tests better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the pinout etc match you can replace with something of the same access time or less. Slower access time can become a problematic, depends on the circuit, cycle time and application. There is a reason they chose that speed. Generally the faster the chip the higher the cost.The speed and manufacturer of the chips normally does not matter as long as the specifications are at least equal to or better then the one being replaced. Sometimes chips are chosen for some non data sheet parameter, we have no way of knowing that here unless you consult with the OEM. These parts normally do not fail, determining what happened can save you from future failures.